# jQuery - how to show message if > 1 checkbox selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Depending on the number `n` of cars a user has in his records, there will be `n` checkboxes to select from.

In my view these checkboxes are rendered using a loop

```
<?php 
foreach ($cars as $row):
echo form_checkbox('cars_id[]', $row->cars_id, FALSE, 'class="checkbox"') . 
<span>'. $row->cars_name . '</span><br />';
endforeach; 
?>
```

I want to show a message if the user selects > 1 checkbox --- so:

```
[x] Honda
[ ] Toyota
[ ] Suzuki

//no message shown


[x] Honda
[X] Toyota
[ ] Suzuki

//message is shown
```

I have tried doing this without success using variations of

```
if ($(".checkbox").is(':checked')) { etc...
```

Does anyone have suggestions how to get this to work?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to show message if > 1 checkbox selected?

You could check the `length` property of the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) checkboxes.

```
if ($('.checkbox:checked').length > 1) { 
   // Show message.
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bSCYx/).

Also, you could select those checkboxes with [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector.

Comment: thanks @alex - i'm trying your suggestion with `if ($('.checkbox:checked').length > 1) { 
 alert("testing");
};` but it doesn't work - am I doing anything wrong here? no errors on console

Comment: @torr Not that I can see. I'm going to make a fiddle.

Comment: hey @alex i'm trying to make the message disappear if the user goes back to a single checkbox selected -- here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k7cf/1/) -- any suggestions?

Comment: @torr Your JavaScript was wrong. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/2k7cf/2/).